# laravel auth:api not working and is redirecting

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, laravel-routing

Laravel is an upgraded to 5.5. I have a client that is sending an application/json post using auth code grant.

my route is:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api','middleware' => ['auth:api']], function () {
    Route::post('client', 'AlexaController@post');
});
```

I have looked and I don't have a api.php file.

Also the kernel doesn't show a `'auth:api'` in the `$routeMiddleware`.

I am not getting any errors at all and the client is getting a 302 error (redirect).

What am I missing?

Comment: most likely csrf token may be missing.

Comment: maybe give this a try: php artisan route:clear

Comment: I figured out when updated laravel from 5.2 to 5.3 the routes changed. Once I update the routes like laravel 5.5 and used the api.php for my route it works.